# Codeigniter: Adding an extra column in a default generated table

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

How do I add an extra column to the left side of a generated table? 
I seriously have no idea how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

(A snippet of my code)

```
$this->load->library('table');
        $this->table->set_caption($campagne);
        $this->table->set_heading('Campagne','Datum','Eindecode', 'Totaal',       '09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30', '19:00', '19:30');
$template = array(
        'table_open'            => '<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">',

        'thead_open'            => '<thead>',
        'thead_close'           => '</thead>',

        'heading_row_start'     => '<tr>',
        'heading_row_end'       => '</tr>',
        'heading_cell_start'    => '<th>',
        'heading_cell_end'      => '</th>',

        'tbody_open'            => '<tbody>',
        'tbody_close'           => '</tbody>',

        'row_start'             => '<tr>',
        'row_end'               => '</tr>',
        'cell_start'            => '<td>',
        'cell_end'              => '</td>',

        'row_alt_start'         => '<tr>',
        'row_alt_end'           => '</tr>',
        'cell_alt_start'        => '<td>',
        'cell_alt_end'          => '</td>',

        'table_close'           => '</table>'
            );

    $this->table->set_template($template);     
    return $this->table->generate($query1);
```

Sorry, I can't show you everything because of sensitive information

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide us a screenshot of this script's result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add a new column in the left side, including a first element in every row of your $query1 . For example,

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($query1); $i++){
  array_unshift($query1[$i], $element); 
}     
return $this->table->generate($query1);
```

Where $element should be what you want in each case.
Hope to help you!
Thanks.